# AWS get object from one bucket and place it in another bucket

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

i'm trying to get object from one AWS account S3 to another account S3. Currently i make that functionality with temporary directory like so:

```
$s3_remote = S3Client::factory(/*AWS logins*/);
$s3_local = S3Client::factory(/*AWS logins*/);

$s3_remote->getObject([
     "Bucket" => $bucket,
     "Key" => $object,
     "SaveAs" => $path . $name . "." . $extension,
]);

$s3_local->putObject([
     "Bucket" => $bucket,
     "Key" => $object,
     "SourceFile" => $path . $name . "." . $extension,
]);
```

Is there any way to `getObject` directly to local S3 bucket from remote-one?

Is there something like:

```
$s3_remote->getObject(
    "Bucket" => $bucket,
    "Key" => $key
    "LocalAWSKey" => "13265ASD",
    "LocalAWSSKey" => "aASd31a2sd13as564fsdg4aA"
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can setup permissions to allow one account access to another account's S3 resources. See the [Access Control](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingAuthAccess.html) section of the S3 Developer Guide. Once the appropriate permissions are in place, you should be able to use the `S3Client::copyObject()` method.